# How To Click A Button In The WebBrowser

Tags: .net, vb.net, browser, webbrowser-control

I'm creating a program that logs you into a site, and clicks on a button the page. This button isn't like a normal button that can be invoked using this script:

```
WebBrowser).Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")
```

The button when clicked manually in my project, opens up a Internet Explorer session and navigates to the page.

The Source for the Button:

```
<form id="vform1" action="/account/vote/" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
<div class="cpBtn" style="height:38px; width:95px;" onclick="document.getElementById('vform1').submit();">
<p style="margin:11px auto;">Open WoW</p></div></form>
```

My Question: How do I click this button using a VB.net script and how do I make it open in a new tab and not in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page, IPostBackEventHandler

{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

div1.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "ClickDiv");

}

protected void Div1_Click()

{

// Do something

}

#region IPostBackEventHandler Members

public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)

{

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventArgument))

{

if (eventArgument == "ClickDiv")

{

Div1_Click();

}

}

}

#endregion

}
```

Convert it to VB.Net

reference :: [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1090438.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways for this :

1- with divisions selector

'Get all divisions in your webbrowser1 :

```
 Dim divs As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
```

'Go to the spesified div and click on it:

```
for each mydiv as Htmlelement in divs

if (mydiv .GetAttribute("class").Tostring = "cpBtn" ) then mydiv.InvokeMember("Click") 

next
```

2- with form selector

```
Dim forms As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("form")
 for each myform as Htmlelement in forms

if (myform.GetAttribute("id").Tostring = "vform1" ) then myform.InvokeMember("Submit") 

next
```

**NOTE:** if you know that will be only one form in your webbrowser so just do this :

```
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("form")(0).InvokeMember("Submit")
```